# My Laptop is running very slow when I installed ubuntu

Tags: performance

I recently installed Ubuntu on my laptop, I have a pretty decent configuration that supports windows 8 very fluently but Ubuntu lags a lot while operating.

This is my Laptop's configuration:

> Processor Intel i5-2430M
>  Clock Speed    2.4 GHz
>  Cores 2
>   cores
>  Instruction Set        64 bit
>  Memory Bandwidth  21.3
>   GB/s
>  Number of Threads  4
>  MEMORY
>  RAM Included   6 GB RAM Possible   8 GB
>  RAM Type DDR3
>  RAM Speed    1,333 MHz

Comment: It should not be slow. Which version of ubuntu are you using? are you using wubi installation or native installation or running in virtual machine? Have you checked for `additional drivers`?

Comment: I used Wubi installer. And I have the drivers needed.